# Force React to render String object as string literal

Tags: reactjs

Due to some hackery I have in place for localization, many of the strings displayed in my app are `String` objects rather than string literals.  The end result is the same, however when looking at the DOM and jest snapshots, there is one text node per character in the element's children.

Just for quality of life/readability reasons, is there a way to force React to render `String`s as literals through something equally hacky (or a plugin or something)?

Answer (score 0):

You can either call `toString()` on every `String` instance, or you can make them template literals like `${this is my string object}`

Inside a div this would look like:

```
<div>{`${myStringObject}`}</div>
```

Comment: I was going for something a little more automatic than that lol

Comment: Hmm, all I can think of is you write a function that converts a string object into a fragment containing the string using a template literal like `const asString = strObj => <>{`${strObj}`}</>` and then use that inside curly braces every time you use a string... Anything more automated than that is beyond my JavaScripting and Reacting abilities I'm afraid ^^

Answer (score 0):

I had an epiphany shortly after posting this question.  When a `String` is being rendered as individual text nodes, it's treating the object as an iterable.  So, all I have to do is override the `[Symbol.iterable]` method of the `String`s in question.

```js
function* flattenString() {
  yield this.toString();
}

const myString = new Proxy(localize.t(myStringKey), {
  t(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
     // allows templatizing the string via i18next
     // ...
  },
  [Symbol.iterator]: flattenString,
});
```

Now, instead of yielding one character at a time, it will just yield the whole thing at once and then be done.

This doesn't work for Enzyme snapshots when a `String` is passed in as a property of a `ReactElement`, but at least it looks nice in the DOM and in cases where the child is the localized string.